# Resize a numpy array of lists so that so that the lists all have the same length and dtype of numpy array can be inferred correctly

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I currently have the following `dataframe`

```
data = {'col_a': [['a', 'b'], ['a', 'b', 'c'], ['a'], ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], ['a', 'b', 'c'], ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']],
        'col_b':[[1, 3], [1, 0, 0], [4], [1, 1, 2, 0], [0, 0, 5], [3, 1, 2, 5]]}
df= pd.DataFrame(data)
```

Suppose I work with `col_a`, I want to resize the lists in `col_a` in a vectorized manner so that the `length of all the sub lists = max length of largest list` and I want to fill the empty values with `'None'` in the case of `col_a`. I want the final output to look as follows

```
                   col_a               col_b
0     [a, b, None, None]    [1, 3, nan, nan]
1        [a, b, c, None]      [1, 0, 0, nan]
2  [a, None, None, None]  [4, nan, nan, nan]
3           [a, b, c, d]        [1, 1, 2, 0]
4        [a, b, c, None]      [0, 0, 5, nan]
5           [a, b, c, d]        [3, 1, 2, 5]
```

So far I have done the following

```
# Convert the column to a NumPy array with object dtype
col_np = df['col_a'].to_numpy()

# Find the maximum length of the lists using NumPy operations
max_length = np.max(np.frompyfunc(len, 1, 1)(col_np))

# Create a mask for padding
mask = np.arange(max_length) < np.frompyfunc(len, 1, 1)(col_np)[:, None]

# Pad the lists with None where necessary
result = np.where(mask, col_np, 'None')
```

This results in the following error
`ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (6,4) (6,) ()`

I feel like I'm close but there's something that I'm missing here. Please note that only **vectorized** solutions will be marked as the answer.

Comment: Even with equal size lists, you desired dataframe columns are `object` dtype, and contain lists (or possibly arrays).  Nothing is stored as a (6,4) array.  The strings and `None` of the first column are python objects.  The second column lists have a mix of int and float values.

Comment: `col_np` is a (6,) shape object dtype arrays, containing lists.  You managed with a pseudo-vectorization to make a (6,4) `mask`..  But arguments to `where` have to `broadcast` together.  `np.where(mask, col_np[:,None], 'None']` might run, but that isn't going to replace individual items of the `col_np` lists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Only vectorized solutions will be marked as the answer.* -> that's too bad because no (true) vectorized approach is possible with an array of lists. To this extent, `np.frompyfunc` is certainly not truly vectorized.

If by "vectorized" you mean without explicit python loop, you could use:

```
df['out_a'] = pd.Series(pd.DataFrame(df['col_a'].to_numpy().tolist()).to_numpy().tolist())
```

An alternative with an explicit loop would be:

```
size = df['col_a'].str.len().max()

df['out_a'] = [l+[None]*(size-len(l)) for l in df['col_a']]
```

Output:

```
          col_a         col_b                  out_a
0        [a, b]        [1, 3]     [a, b, None, None]
1     [a, b, c]     [1, 0, 0]        [a, b, c, None]
2           [a]           [4]  [a, None, None, None]
3  [a, b, c, d]  [1, 1, 2, 0]           [a, b, c, d]
4     [a, b, c]     [0, 0, 5]        [a, b, c, None]
5  [a, b, c, d]  [3, 1, 2, 5]           [a, b, c, d]
```

##### timings

For small lists the "vectorized" and loop solution have very similar timings.

Here for lists with 1 to 10 items:

[image]

However, when the size of lists increases, the python loop become more efficient.

For list with 0 to 50 items:

[image]

0 to 200 items:

[image]

0 to 2000 items:

[image]

Code used for the timings:

```
import pandas as pd
import perfplot
import numpy as np

def pandas_vectorized(df):
    df['out_a'] = pd.Series(pd.DataFrame(df['col_a'].to_numpy().tolist()).to_numpy().tolist())
    
def python_loop(df):
    size = df['col_a'].str.len().max()
    df['out_a'] = [l+[None]*(size-len(l)) for l in df['col_a']]

MAX_LIST_SIZE = 2000
    
perfplot.show(
    setup=lambda n: pd.DataFrame({'col_a': [['x']*n for n in np.random.randint(0, MAX_LIST_SIZE, size=n)]}),
    kernels=[pandas_vectorized, python_loop],
    n_range=[2**k for k in range(1, 18)],  # upper bound was 22 for small lists
    xlabel="len(df)",
    equality_check=None,
    max_time=10,
)
```

Comment: thank you. Which of the following approaches would you suggest for a `df` with 10k records? 

1.  Processing the columns the way you mentioned above and then treating them as `NumPy` arrays of `dtype` `string` and `float` respectively and then applying other downstream `vectorized` calculations
2. Using `np.frompyfunc` on the array of lists and then applying other downstream 'vectorized' calculations

I understand my question below might not conform to SO etiquette, however, I would deeply appreciate your input on which of the above, going by your gut, would be more performant.

Comment: What is the maximum list size? I added timings to compare the efficiencies for various possibilities. Overall I would recommend the loop, it's likely faster and probably more memory efficient.

Comment: Super helpful visualizations! Thank you so much. Could you please share with me resources on how you benchmarked these? I would like to learn. **Edit:** Just saw your updated answer with the code for benchmarking. Thanks a ton!

Comment: Note that `max(map(len, df['col_a']))` should be faster than `df['col_a'].str.len().max()` in the loop approach. edit: indeed it is [marginally faster](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CETyc.png)

Comment: So it's the `pd.DataFrame(df['col_a'].to_numpy().tolist())` that expands the one Series to multiple columns with fill values.  I wonder if there's a `pandas` method to do this kind of `expand/explode`?

Comment: @hpaulj yes, you could `explode`, deduplicate the index, `pivot` or `unstack` but this is likely even less efficient

Answer (score 1):

This is basically a `padding` question - expanding lists to the matching length by adding fill values.  This has come up a number times.

`itertools` has a variant on `zip` that is useful for this:

```
In [273]: from itertools import zip_longest
```

Your column:

```
In [274]: x=df.col_a.to_numpy()
In [275]: x
Out[275]: 
array([list(['a', 'b']), list(['a', 'b', 'c']), list(['a']),
       list(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']), list(['a', 'b', 'c']),
       list(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'])], dtype=object)
```

This pads, but it's the transpose of what we want:

```
In [276]: list(zip_longest(*x))
Out[276]: 
[('a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a'),
 ('b', 'b', None, 'b', 'b', 'b'),
 (None, 'c', None, 'c', 'c', 'c'),
 (None, None, None, 'd', None, 'd')]
```

We could use an array transpose, but there's a list idiom that does the same:

```
In [277]: list(zip(*(zip_longest(*x))))
Out[277]: 
[('a', 'b', None, None),
 ('a', 'b', 'c', None),
 ('a', None, None, None),
 ('a', 'b', 'c', 'd'),
 ('a', 'b', 'c', None),
 ('a', 'b', 'c', 'd')]
```

And the same thing applied to the numeric column, with `nan` fill:

```
In [281]: list(zip(*(zip_longest(*df.col_b, fillvalue=np.nan))))
Out[281]: 
[(1, 3, nan, nan),
 (1, 0, 0, nan),
 (4, nan, nan, nan),
 (1, 1, 2, 0),
 (0, 0, 5, nan),
 (3, 1, 2, 5)]
```

For large lists of lists there are faster padding methods, but this `zip_longest` is one of the easier ones to remember and use.

### edit

With your code, `mask` is a good looking array, telling where we want the fill values:

```
In [285]: mask
Out[285]: 
array([[ True,  True, False, False],
       [ True,  True,  True, False],
       [ True, False, False, False],
       [ True,  True,  True,  True],
       [ True,  True,  True, False],
       [ True,  True,  True,  True]])
```

It's (6,4).  To be used in `where` where have to expand `col_np` to (6,1):

```
In [286]: result = np.where(mask, col_np[:,None], 'None')
     ...:
```

But the result is hardly what we want:

```
In [287]: result
Out[287]: 
array([[list(['a', 'b']), list(['a', 'b']), 'None', 'None'],
       [list(['a', 'b', 'c']), list(['a', 'b', 'c']),
        list(['a', 'b', 'c']), 'None'],
       [list(['a']), 'None', 'None', 'None'],
       [list(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']), list(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']),
        list(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']), list(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'])],
       [list(['a', 'b', 'c']), list(['a', 'b', 'c']),
        list(['a', 'b', 'c']), 'None'],
       [list(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']), list(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']),
        list(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']), list(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'])]],
      dtype=object)
```

However there is a way of using that mask to fill an array.  First make the target with the right shape and dtype:

```
In [288]: result = np.empty((6,4),object)
In [289]: result
Out[289]: 
array([[None, None, None, None],
       [None, None, None, None],
       [None, None, None, None],
       [None, None, None, None],
       [None, None, None, None],
       [None, None, None, None]], dtype=object)
In [290]: result[mask] = np.hstack(col_np)
In [291]: result
Out[291]: 
array([['a', 'b', None, None],
       ['a', 'b', 'c', None],
       ['a', None, None, None],
       ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'],
       ['a', 'b', 'c', None],
       ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']], dtype=object)
```

This fill works because `result[mask]` is a flat array of values:

```
In [292]: result[mask]
Out[292]: 
array(['a', 'b', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'a', 'b', 'c',
       'a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], dtype=object)
```

Overall this approach is quite close to one of the more clever, and faster, padding methods that have been proposed.  I believe Warren Weckesser was the original source.

And the numeric column

```
In [300]: result = np.full((6,4),np.nan)
In [301]: result
Out[301]: 
array([[nan, nan, nan, nan],
       [nan, nan, nan, nan],
       [nan, nan, nan, nan],
       [nan, nan, nan, nan],
       [nan, nan, nan, nan],
       [nan, nan, nan, nan]])
In [302]: result[mask] = np.hstack(df.col_b)
In [303]: result
Out[303]: 
array([[ 1.,  3., nan, nan],
       [ 1.,  0.,  0., nan],
       [ 4., nan, nan, nan],
       [ 1.,  1.,  2.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  5., nan],
       [ 3.,  1.,  2.,  5.]])
```

The `mask` can be created with only one list comprehension - to get the length of each list.

```
In [318]: lens = np.array([len(i) for i in x])
In [319]: np.max(lens)
Out[319]: 4
In [320]: mask1 = np.arange(np.max(lens))<lens[:,None]
In [321]: mask1
Out[321]: 
array([[ True,  True, False, False],
       [ True,  True,  True, False],
       [ True, False, False, False],
       [ True,  True,  True,  True],
       [ True,  True,  True, False],
       [ True,  True,  True,  True]])
```

### timings

With Mozway's dataframe expansion:

```
In [325]: timeit pd.DataFrame(df['col_a'].to_numpy().tolist())
296 µs ± 3.17 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1,000 loops each)
In [326]: timeit pd.Series(pd.DataFrame(df['col_a'].to_numpy().tolist()).to_numpy().toli
     ...: st())
567 µs ± 52.8 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1,000 loops each)
```

Packaging the mask approach into a function:

```
def foo(df):
    x = df.col_a.to_numpy()
    lens = np.array([len(i) for i in x])
    mask = np.arange(np.max(lens))<lens[:,None]
    result = np.empty(mask.shape, dtype=object)
    result[mask] = np.hstack(x)
    return result
```

Time to get the padded array:

```
In [337]: timeit foo(df)
74.6 µs ± 3.45 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10,000 loops each)
```

and converting that array to a Series:

```
In [341]: timeit pd.Series(foo(df).tolist())
299 µs ± 68.6 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1,000 loops each)
```

and the zip_longest approach (fastest for this size)

```
In [344]: pd.Series(list(zip(*(zip_longest(*df.col_a)))))
Out[344]: 
0       (a, b, None, None)
1          (a, b, c, None)
2    (a, None, None, None)
3             (a, b, c, d)
4          (a, b, c, None)
5             (a, b, c, d)
dtype: object
In [345]: timeit list(zip(*(zip_longest(*df.col_a))))
19.7 µs ± 151 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100,000 loops each)
In [346]: timeit pd.Series(list(zip(*(zip_longest(*df.col_a)))))
165 µs ± 29.6 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10,000 loops each)
```

Comment: This however assumes that you already have the mask, which is not cheap to compute. Have you tried to time the complete solution?

Comment: @mozway, though creating the mask isn't too expensive.  It only needs one list comprehension, to get the list lengths.  The rest is an array comparison.  But I've added a basic set of timings - your pandas expansion, this mask, and the zip_longest.  The usual cautions about scaling to larger examples apply.

Comment: @hpaulj thank you for your answer! It's definitely helped me understand `numpy` vectorization better.